# mongodb Connection reset by peer : socket writer error

Tags: java, mongodb, database-connection

I am receiving the error below "*sometimes*" during update mongodb

2012-03-06 00:09:39,733 SEVERE [com.mongodb.tcp] (http-0.0.0.0-80-169) MyPort.error called
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error

```
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
at org.bson.io.PoolOutputBuffer.pipe(PoolOutputBuffer.java:113)
at com.mongodb.OutMessage.pipe(OutMessage.java:157)
at com.mongodb.DBPort.go(DBPort.java:92)
at com.mongodb.DBPort.go(DBPort.java:66)
at com.mongodb.DBPort.say(DBPort.java:61)
at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.say(DBTCPConnector.java:155)
at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.say(DBTCPConnector.java:141)
at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.update(DBApiLayer.java:299)
at com.mongodb.DBCollection.update(DBCollection.java:125)
    at com.zimbra.actions.DataSave.exec(DataSave.java:46)
```

Let's check DataSave.java :

```
DBCollection clDatum = com.zimbra.getSystemMongo().getCollection("datum");
BasicDBObject mySearch = new BasicDBObject();
mySearch.put("Id", 12132);
BasicDBObject myReplacement = new BasicDBObject();
myReplacement.put("$set", new BasicDBObject("A.B",
 (JSONObject) JSONValue.parse(request.getParameter("data").toString());));
// I am getting this error here (line 46):
clDatum.update(mySearch, myReplacement, true, true);
```

If you think I am trying to write more data than the server supplies, can you tell me where should I check? Is there any where to change this size?

Or could you pass me any idea to solve this problem ?

Thanks a lot..

Answer (score 1):

Probably this is because driver does not reconnect to mongodb after timeout exception, you have to handle it manually in your code.

Driver can't remove dropped socket from connection from pool until your code try use it. So in general you need `try {} catch {}` and repeat update twice, if second time you get error you should throw it.

At least c# driver have same behavior, because it can't really control and remove dropped sockets (because they can be closed at any time), so you have to just handle it manually.